# Ruby 2.0 on Mac 10.5.8 via RVM

Tags: rvm, osx-leopard, ruby-2.0

I have been having some issues with my Ruby and Gem environments and wanted to clean them all out and start over. So I removed all my ruby's in rvm (`rvm 1.13.8 (stable)`) which left me with the stock Ruby 1.8.6 and Gem 1.0.1. I thought about removing these as well but everything I read said they should be fine. Anyway I went to install Ruby 2.0 but RVM has 1.9.3 as the most current and I was wondering if its because I am running 10.5.8 on a G4 MDD and if there is a possibility of being able to install it. My MacBook Pro running 10.8 was able to install it.

```
$ rvm list known
# MRI Rubies
[ruby-]1.8.6[-p420]
[ruby-]1.8.7[-p358]
[ruby-]1.8.7-head
[ruby-]1.9.1[-p431]
[ruby-]1.9.2-p180
[ruby-]1.9.2-p290
[ruby-]1.9.2-p318
[ruby-]1.9.2[-p320]
[ruby-]1.9.2-head
[ruby-]1.9.3-preview1
[ruby-]1.9.3-rc1
[ruby-]1.9.3-p0
[ruby-]1.9.3-p125
[ruby-]1.9.3-[p194]
[ruby-]1.9.3-head
ruby-head
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update RVM, the versions are part of the update:

```
rvm get head
rvm list known | grep 2.0.0
```

which gives:

```
[ruby-]2.0.0-rc1
[ruby-]2.0.0-rc2
[ruby-]2.0.0[-p0]
rbx-2.0.0-rc1
```

Comment: Sorry I it has taken me so long to update, I was out of town and not able to follow-up. Anyway, that was the trick, thank you very much!